# Is it possible to generate 40,000+ element of Fibonacci recursively in Lisp?

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, fibonacci

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler question 2](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=2) with Lisp. This recursive solution blows the stack on execution, but I thought Lisp (using clisp) would recognize the tail recursion. This is being entered into the top-level.

```
(defun e2-problem (&optional (f1 1) (f2 1) (sum 0))  
   "Sum fibonacci sequence, even terms up to 4 million"

   (if (> f2 4000000) sum)
   (e2-problem f2 (+ f1 f2) (if (evenp f2) 
                                (+ sum f2) 
                               sum))
```

Is my implementation not correctly arranged for optimization? I imagine this would hinder my Lisp education quite a bit if I could not rely on idiomatic recursion.

Comment: Clisp is a CL implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Correct syntax **error** in code:

```
(defun e2-problem (&optional (f1 1) (f2 1) (sum 0))  
   "Sum fibonacci sequence, even terms up to 4 million"
   (if (> f2 4000000) 
       sum   ;; here was a closing bracket 
       (e2-problem f2 (+ f1 f2) (if (evenp f2) 
                                    (+ sum f2) 
                                    sum))))  ;; 2 more brackets here
```

2) use **[SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/platform-table.html)**. CLISP is not kind enough to detect tail recursion.

3) use highest available **optimization** level:

```
(defun e2-problem (&optional (f1 1) (f2 1) (sum 0))  
   "Sum fibonacci sequence, even terms up to 4 million"
   (declare (optimize (debug 0)))  ;; optimization
   ...
```

Comment: Ooops! DEBUG 0, of course. And yes, this is not complete optimization, but it tells to runtime that it may eliminate stack frames, i.e. allow tail recursion.

Comment: CLISP does detect tail recursion.

Answer (score 9):

Recursion (or even iteration) is not necessary!

Every third Fibonacci number is even:

> 1 1 **2** 3 5 **8** 13 21 **34** 55 89 **144** ...

and since each even Fibonacci number (in bold) is the sum of the two preceding odd Fibonacci numbers, the sum of the *even* Fibonacci numbers up to F<sub>*n*</sub> is exactly half of the sum of *all* the Fibonacci numbers up to F<sub>*n*</sub> (if F<sub>*n*</sub> is even, of course).

Now, the sum of the first *n* Fibonacci numbers is F<sub>*n*+2</sub> − 1. This is easy to check by induction: the sum of the first *n* + 1 Fibonacci numbers is F<sub>*1*</sub> + F<sub>*2*</sub> + ... + F<sub>*n*</sub> + F<sub>*n*+1</sub>, which equals F<sub>*n*+2</sub> − 1 + F<sub>*n*+1</sub> by hypothesis, which equals F<sub>*n*+3</sub> − 1 by the definition of the Fibonacci numbers.

So if you can find the largest *N* such that F<sub>3*N*</sub> ≤ 4,000,000, then the sum that’s asked for will be (F<sub>3*N*+2</sub> − 1) / 2.

(I'll leave the remaining details to you but it should be straightforward from here.)

Comment: Interesting! So i guess it comes down to the best way to numerically solve the Binet equation:
4 million = (φ^x-(-1/φ)^x)/√5

My first thought is Newton's method - any better ways?

Comment: You don't need Newton's method: just observe that (1/φ)^x is very small.

Answer (score 4):

> I thought Lisp (using clisp) would recognize the tail recursion

For an environment to implement tail call elimination is [mandatory in Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), but not in most other Lisp dialects, such as Common Lisp.

Comment: Specifically clisp does not optimize tail calls (I thought there was an option to enable, but I can't find it in the manpage), while e.g. sbcl does.

Comment: if it would recognize tail recursion, the example would run forever - without blowing the stack. As an endless loop, since it does not terminate. Well, a number would overflow.

Comment: I see many people saying the code does not terminate. Why doesn't it terminate due to the if statement?

Comment: The `if` ends, and then the next line calls `e2-problem` regardless of what happened there.

Comment: Thank you. I thought Lisp would return result of the first form, but that makes no sense. It returns the last!

Answer (score 2):

Your code implements an endless loop. It does not terminate.

Using LOOP:

```
(defun e2-problem-a (n)
  "Sum fibonacci sequence, even terms up to n"
  (loop for f1 = 1 then f2
        and f2 = 1 then (+ f1 f2)
        while (<= f2 n)
        when (evenp f2) sum f2))
```