# while condition keep on injecting ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to generate fibonacci series in ruby, till the max hits a max value say 50000. 
I wrote the following snippet:

```
high = 50000
arr = [0, 1]

while arr.last < high do
  arr.inject{|a, i| arr.push(arr[-2] + arr[-1])}
end

puts arr.last
```

This causes the program to halt. 
I am actually new to ruby, Is there a good way to tackle ifs and while with `inject` in the same statement in ruby?
What could be a better approach for the above method i am using.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418524/fibonacci-one-liner) for some other approaches to generating the Fibonacci sequence in Ruby.

Comment: question is not more about fibo sequence, its more about using conditions near inject.

Comment: @user993563: the problem is that inject isn't useful at all for the snippet you show (generating fibonacci values).

Comment: okay, probably its my first out, so trying diff. stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `inject` for no apparent reason, `while` + `<<` are enough to accumulate values:

```
fibs = [0, 1]
while fibs.last < 50_000
  fibs << fibs[-2] + fibs[-1]
end
fibs.last # 75025
```

Remember that `inject` folds a collection, you have no collection to fold here, you're generating one, `inject` won't help you.

Comment: yes, i am generating a collection, but there is simple if around that collection, continue till you hit a max, could i place the condition near inject, writing otherwise did not look to me more rubyish, it looks rather rubbish ;-)