# Why doesn't this algorithm yield the fibonacci sequence under 100?

Tags: ruby

```
a = 1; b = 2
fibonacci = []
while fibonacci.length < 100
    fibonacci.push(a)
    fibonacci.push(b)
    a = a + b; b = a + b
end

push fibonacci
```

The error message is "undefined method `push' for main:Obj"

Comment: You're trying to #push the array itself on the last line! :) --That's what it's complaining about -- the method is being invoked on the 'main' object... I'm guessing you mean `puts`

Comment: Thank you! Silly mistake, should have said "puts" @JosephWeissman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to #push the array itself on the last line! :)

That's what it's complaining about. The `push` method is being invoked on the 'main' object, and `push` is not a `Kernel` method.

I'm guessing you mean `puts`. Otherwise it looks okay, if somewhat non-idiomatic. Naturally you can find lots of Ruby solutions for this problem on the site that might read a bit more clearly (see [here for a recursive one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12178708/90042).)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said before the last line should be 'puts'
Also your numbers are wrong.

```
a = 1; b = 1
fibonacci = []
while fibonacci.length < 100
  fibonacci << a
  fibonacci << b
  a += b
  b += a
end

puts fibonacci
```

But also the fib starts at 1 and the the second element is also 1.
This make you sequence off, if you start at 1, 2

Fib = 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...

Comment: Some people consider that 0 and 1 (rather than 1 and 1) are the starting numbers, see for instance [Sloane](http://oeis.org/A000045) (this is just meant to be informative, I'm not trying to nitpick or anything else).

Comment: You are right, in systems, it is at 0, 1, 1, .. But in general, it's 1, 1, but never 1, 2