# How does this block work for Integer times method?

Tags: ruby

I can’t figure out how the `n.times` line works in the ruby code given below, specifically what the commas mean and how the `new` variable is updated.

```
def fib(n)
  raise "fib not defined for negative numbers" if n < 0
  new, old = 1, 0
  n.times {new, old = new + old, new}
  old
end
```

The code works, and was code given by user pjs in response to a question about fibonacci sequences in ruby, at this stackoverflow question: [Ruby Fibonacci algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438655/ruby-fibonacci-algorithm).

I don’t understand what’s going on inside the block.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby supports parallel assignment.

```
new, old = new + old, new
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
temp = [new + old, new]  # right side are evaluated and stored in an array
new, old = temp          # there is a commaa in the left side
                         # so they get the value from the array, one by one
```

Answer (score 2):

`n.times { ... }` will do whatever is inside the block `n` times.  So for example, if `n` is `5`, it's equivalent to:

```
new, old = 1, 0
new, old = new + old, new # new = 1+0 = 1; old = 1
new, old = new + old, new # new = 1+1 = 2; old = 1
new, old = new + old, new # new = 2+1 = 3; old = 2
new, old = new + old, new # new = 3+2 = 5; old = 3
new, old = new + old, new # new = 5+3 = 8; old = 5
old
# => 5
```

The other thing that may be confusing you is the parallel assignment:

```
new, old = new + old, new
```

In general, you can have:

```
a, b = <some-expr>, <some-other-expr>
```

The expressions on the right will be evaluated first, and then `a` will be assigned the first value, `b` the second.  You can use this as a quick way to swap two variables without using a `temp` variable, for example: `a, b = b, a`.