# more efficient Fibonacci for BigInteger

Tags: java, performance, recursion, dynamic, fibonacci

I am working on a class project to create a more efficient Fibonacci than the recursive version of `Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)`. For this project I need to use `BigInteger`. So far I have had the idea to use a map to store the previous fib numbers.

```
public static BigInteger theBigFib(BigInteger n) {

    Map<BigInteger, BigInteger> store = new TreeMap<BigInteger, BigInteger>(); 

    if (n.intValue()<= 2){
        return BigInteger.ONE;

    }else if(store.containsKey(n)){         
        return store.get(n);    

    }else{
        BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
        BigInteger val = theBigFib(n.subtract(one)).add(theBigFib(n.subtract(two)));
        store.put(n,val);           
        return val;
    }

}
```

I think that the map is storing more than it should be. I also think this line

`BigInteger val = theBigFib(n.subtract(one)).add(theBigFib(n.subtract(two)));`

is an issue. If anyone could shed some light on what i'm doing wrong or possible another solution to make it faster than the basic code.
Thanks!

Comment: You can use a normal ArrayList as well if u want to store all the fibonacci numbers upto n.

Comment: I think you are over complicating the problem, all you need is the last 2 results so `BigInteger[2]` acting like a stack suffices.

Comment: @AimeeBorda agree, if op just need the final answer , it can be done with 3 variables as well

Comment: If you want to generate ***really*** big Fibonacci numbers you shouldn't attempt to store all prior values, and you won't want to use an O(n) approach.  Consider the O(log n) matrix approach in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438655/ruby-fibonacci-algorithm/24439070#24439070).  It will easily map to Java.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need all the previous `BigIntegers`, you just need the last `2`.

Instead of a recursive solution you can use a loop.

```
public static BigInteger getFib(int n) {
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger b = new BigInteger.ONE;

    if (n < 2) {
        return a;
    }
    BigInteger c = null;
    while (n-- >= 2) {
        c = a.add(b);
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    return c;
}
```

If you want to store all the previous values, you can use an array instead.

```
static BigInteger []memo = new BigInteger[MAX];
public static BigInteger getFib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return new BigInteger("1");
    }

    if (memo[n] != null) {
        return memo[n];
    }

    memo[n] = getFib(n - 1).add(getFib(n - 2));
    return memo[n];
}
```

---

If you just want the nth Fib value fast and efficient.

You can use the [matrix form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) of fibonacci.

```
A = 1 1
    1 0

A^n = F(n + 1) F(n)
      F(n)     F(n - 1)
```

You can efficiently calculate A^n using [Exponentiation by Squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: Replace `new BigInteger("1")` with [`BigInteger.ONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ONE), and get rid of `new BigInteger("0")`. You should just declare `c` where it's used, i.e. `BigInteger c = a.add(b);`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main issue in your code is that you create a new `Map` on each function call. Note that it's still local variable, despite that your method is `static`. So, you're guaranteed that the `store.containsKey(n)` condition never holds and your solution is not better than naive. I.e. it still has exponential complexity of `n`. More precisely, it takes about `F(n)` steps to get to the answer (basically because all "ones" that make up your answer are returned by some function call).

I'd suggest making the variable a `static` field instead of a local variable. Then number of calls should become linear instead of exponential and you will see a significant improvement. Other solutions include `for` loop with three variables which iteratively calculate Fibonacci numbers from 0, 1, 2 up to `n`-th and the best solutions I know involve matrix exponentiation or explicit formula with real numbers (which is bad for precision), but it's a question better suited for computer science StackExchange website, imho.