# Why is my recursive Fibonacci implementation so slow compared to an iterative one?

Tags: performance, recursion, rust, benchmarking

I have created the following simple Fibonacci implementations:

```
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;

pub fn fibonacci_recursive(n: u32) -> u32 {
    match n {
        0 => 0,
        1 => 1,
        _ => fibonacci_recursive(n - 1) + fibonacci_recursive(n - 2)
    }
}

pub fn fibonacci_imperative(n: u32) -> u32 {
    match n {
        0 => 0,
        1 => 1,
        _ => {
            let mut penultimate;
            let mut last = 1;
            let mut fib = 0;
            for _ in 0..n {
                penultimate = last;
                last = fib;
                fib = penultimate + last;
            }
            fib
        }
    }
}
```

I created them to try out `cargo bench`, so I wrote the following benchmarks:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use test::Bencher;

    #[bench]
    fn bench_fibonacci_recursive(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let n = test::black_box(20);
            fibonacci_recursive(n)
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_fibonacci_imperative(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let n = test::black_box(20);
            fibonacci_imperative(n)
        });
    }
}
```

I know that a recursive implementation is generally slower than an imperative one, especially since Rust doesn't support tail recursion optimization (which this implementation couldn't use anyways). But I was not expecting the following difference of nearly 2'000 times:

```
running 2 tests
test tests::bench_fibonacci_imperative ... bench:          15 ns/iter (+/- 3)
test tests::bench_fibonacci_recursive  ... bench:      28,435 ns/iter (+/- 1,114)
```

I ran it both on Windows and Ubuntu with the newest Rust nightly compiler (`rustc 1.25.0-nightly`) and obtained similar results.

Is this speed difference normal? Did I write something "wrong"? Or are my benchmarks flawed?

Comment: You've implemented entirely different algorithms.  Your recursive implementation keeps re-evaluating intermediate calculations, and is O(2^n), you imperative one is O(n).  This is a well-known result.  Choose a different implementation for the recursive one.  Here are some alternative implementations, albeit not in rust: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24439070/2166798

Comment: Simple. You are recalculating the same values over and over in your recursive implementation. For example, think about how f(n) calculates f(n-1) and f(n-2), but f(n-1) has already calculated f(n-2) which you are not taking advantage of. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/360748/912144

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes sense :) Going to rewrite the function to use memoization and then run `cargo bench` again for an answer. If any of you wants to write it instead, I will accept that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As said by Shepmaster, you should use accumulators to keep the previously calculated `fib(n - 1)` and `fib(n - 2)` otherwise you keep calculating the same values:

```
pub fn fibonacci_recursive(n: u32) -> u32 {
    fn inner(n: u32, penultimate: u32, last: u32) -> u32 {
        match n {
            0 => penultimate,
            1 => last,
            _ => inner(n - 1, last, penultimate + last),
        }
    }
    inner(n, 0, 1)
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(fibonacci_recursive(0), 0);
    assert_eq!(fibonacci_recursive(1), 1);
    assert_eq!(fibonacci_recursive(2), 1);
    assert_eq!(fibonacci_recursive(20), 6765);
}
```

`last` is equivalent to `fib(n - 1)`.
`penultimate` is equivalent to `fib(n - 2)`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to accept this answer because it shows people that might stumble on this how to improve it. By the way, `cargo bench` shows that this solution only takes `2 ns/iter`

Comment: @JanNilsFerner Looks like tail call optimization is at work ;) I read that in *some* circumstances (not guaranteed) LLVM can do TCO.

Comment: @Boiethios: Indeed. Basically TCO boils down to: the recursive call is the *last* thing that your function does. Here, the last line of `inner` is called `inner` so it qualifies... although it's not always as obvious in C++ or Rust because of destructors, which are executed last even though they don't appear in the code and therefore may prevent TCO. Here, no destructor, everything's fine :)

Comment: I just realized that your implementation has a tiny flaw in it: It underflows on zero

Comment: @JanNilsFerner Done

Comment: @Boiethios Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The algorithmic complexity between the two implementations differs:

- your iterative implementation uses an accumulator: O(N),
- your recursive implementation doesn't: O(1.6<sup>N</sup>).

Since 20 (N) << 12089 (1.6<sup>N</sup>), it's pretty normal to have a large difference.

*See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence) for an exact computation of the complexity in the naive implementation case.*

*Note: the method you use for the iterative case is called [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).*

Comment: Thank you for the more analytical answer, it's quite interesting. Also, I didn't know about the term "dynamic programming", so thanks for that link as well!

Comment: Or you could say the recursive version has `O(Fib(N))` complexity.  In fact, [`θ(Fib(n))` is an exact bound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22084314/224132), and `3 * Fib(N) - 3` is the number of additions performed.  (Of course, the recursing and comparing against the base case costs more time than the actual addition, so better just stick to the complexity class!)