# Fibonacci with Ruby

Tags: ruby

[This](https://www.codewars.com/kata/fibonacci-reloaded/ruby) was a problem, which i solved:

```
@cache={}
@cache[1]=0
@cache[2]=1

def fib(n)
  @fibs[n-1]
end

def fib_m(n)
  @cache[n] ||= fib_m(n-1) + fib_m(n-2)
end

@fibs=[]
@fibs=(1..100000).map{|n| fib_m(n)}
```

But this looks hacky. It seems like I am doubling the caching, and I have to hard code some upper limit. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Check for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438655/ruby-fibonacci-algorithm

Comment: What is CW? .......

Comment: CW is codewars, programming site.

Comment: Don't assume that everyone knows that.

Comment: @sawa you mean it should be _"which I solved"_?

Comment: Of course. As I have edited before your edit.

Comment: iGian, thanks for the link, the above is what I am up with after that link and a few others. It works, is performant, but is just hacky.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a cleaner way to do this?

You can assign a [`default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) to calculate missing hash values dynamically:

```
fib = { 0 => 0, 1 => 1 }
fib.default_proc = ->(f, n) { f[n] = f[n-1] + f[n-2] }

fib[10]
#=> 55

fib
#=> {0=>0, 1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>3, 5=>5, 6=>8, 7=>13, 8=>21, 9=>34, 10=>55}
```

Note that this approach is limited by Ruby's stack size.

Comment: Nice way of using `default_proc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable tail call optimization in Ruby, you might achieve the same result recursively, which is faster, less memory consuming and more elegant.

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = {
  tailcall_optimization: true,  
  trace_instruction: false  
}

def fib(curr = 1, acc = 0, n)
  n <= 0 ? acc : fib(acc, curr + acc, n - 1)
end

fib(100_000).to_s.length
#⇒ 20899
```

Comment: Note that `RubyVM` is a private internal implementation detail of YARV, and will not work on MRI (which some tutorials still use), JRuby, IronRuby, Rubinius, MagLev, or Opal. Also note that neither the Ruby Language Specification, nor RubySpec, nor Programming Ruby, nor the RDoc documentation guarantee TCO.