# Fibonacci number on a range (ruby)

Tags: ruby

Could someone give me a brief explanation as to why n+(n-1) doesn't work? Mathematically it does but i'm not sure how to tell ruby this is what i'm looking for? As the title suggests, the code is supposed to return a Fibonacci sequence.

```
startyear = []
(1..100).each do |n|
  puts n+(n-1)
  startyear.push(n)
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fibonacci sequence in Ruby (recursion)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178642/fibonacci-sequence-in-ruby-recursion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n+(n-1) = 2n-1`. Your code is simply displaying `2n-1` (1,3,5,7,..,199).

On the other hand, `startyear.push(n)` is pushing numbers (1,2,3,.,100) into the `startyear` array. I think you meant to do something like this.

```
startyear = [1,1]
(2..100).each do |n|
  puts (new_num = startyear[n-1] + startyear[n-2])
  startyear.push(new_num)
end
```

But again, I'm not 100% sure what the range stands for in your code, so I might be wrong.

Comment: the range is meant to break to code when the value reaches => 100

Comment: I think this answers my question, I added a break into the code. Thank you!