# Ruby recursion calling its own function as argument

Tags: ruby, function, recursion

How can I call "multiple recursive function" in Ruby that takes the function as an argument over and over again?

By that, I don't mean the usual recursive function like [fibonacci sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178642/fibonacci-sequence-in-ruby-recursion). Let's say I have a function called `hey()`. It prints the string `"Hey"` as many times as the function is *called within the function.* To clarify:

```
hey() #=> "Hey "
hey(hey()) #=> "Hey Hey "
hey(hey(hey())) #=> "Hey Hey Hey "
```

I tried

```
def hey(*args)
    "Hey "
end

def hey(*args)
    "Hey " + hey(*args)
end

def hey(n)
    "Hey " + hey(n)
end
```

I have never seen any example like this before. I know it is doable, but not sure how. Is *`args` required? Do I need to pass regular argument instead of `*args`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
def hey(str="")
  "Hey " + str
end

p hey(hey(hey())) # "Hey Hey Hey "
```